# TypeError: plugin.warn is not a function at SQLitePluginTransaction.addStatement

Tags: react-native, sqlite, react-native-sqlite-storage

Getting below error while inserting data into the a table in React native Sqlite DB

Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: plugin.warn is not a function
TypeError: plugin.warn is not a function
at SQLitePluginTransaction.addStatement (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:416247:18)
at SQLitePluginTransaction.executeSql (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:416228:10)
at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:415677:42
at tryCallTwo (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:27207:7)
at doResolve (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:27371:15)
at new Promise (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:27230:5)
at SQLitePluginTransaction.plugin.. [as executeSql] (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:415656:23)
at SQLitePluginTransaction.fn (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:415583:15)
at SQLitePluginTransaction.start (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:416184:12)
at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:415866:32

Below is the code to insert data into DB

````
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.transaction((trans) => {
                trans.executeSql(
                    sql,
                    params,
                    (trans, results) => {
                        resolve(results);
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        reject(error);
                    }
                );
            });
        });
    }; ```
````